# ApplicationCache won't cache anything

Tags: html, application-cache

I'm trying to make a web-app viewable when offline.

- My `index.html` references the manifest like so: `<!DOCTYPE html manifest="manifest.appcache">`
- The MIME type is correct: my `.htaccess` has `AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache`

This is what `manifest.appcache` looks like:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2012-09-28:v1

CACHE:
style.css
images/logo.png
```

However, nothing is cached.

When I call `applicationCache.status` in a javascript console, it returns `0` (I think it should return `1` if successful). 
In Chrome, viewing `chrome://appcache-internals/` also reveals that there are no application caches.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked your MIME type in the browser's dev tool's network console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was stupid. Here's what I was doing wrong:

```
<!DOCTYPE html manifest="manifest.appcache">
```

Should've been:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="manifest.appcache">
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was absolutely going insane looking for a  solution.